# Junit test for saving data with JPA

Tags: spring, jpa, junit

Am trying to make a junit test to save data with JPA. Below is my entity class

```
@Entity
@Table(name="book")
public class test {
@Id
@GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.AUTO)
@Column(name="BOOK_REF_ID",nullable=false)
private int bookRefId;
@Column(name="BOOK_CODE",nullable=false)
private String bookCode;
@Column(name="BOOK_NAME",nullable=false)
private String bookDescription;

public int getBookRefId() {
    return bookRefId;
}
public void setBookRefId(int bookRefId) {
    this.bookRefId = bookRefId;
}
public String getBookCode() {
    return bookCode;
}
public void setBookCode(String bookCode) {
    this.bookCode = bookCode;
}
public String getBookDescription() {
    return bookDescription;
}
public void setBookDescription(String bookDescription) {
    this.bookDescription = bookDescription;
}
}
```

Service class is

```
public interface BookService()
    {
     public Book create(Book book); 
    }
```

Repository class is

```
    public interface BookRepository extends 
    JpaRepository<Book,Integer>
    {  }
```

Service Implementation class is

```
    public BookServiceImpli implements BookService()
    {
     @Resource
     BookRepository repository;
    @Override
    public Book create(Book book) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    return repository.save(book);
    }
    }
```

Now my test class is

```
    @RunWith(SpringRunner.class)
    @DataJpaTest
    @SpringBootTest(classes= {JPAConfig.class})
    @AutoConfigureTestDatabase(replace=Replace.NONE)
    @TestPropertySource(
      locations = "classpath:application.properties")
    public class TestBook {
    @Autowired
    private BookService bookService ;
    @Test
    public void test() {
    Book book = new Book();
    book.setBookCode("abc");
    book.setBookDescription("safd");
    bookService.create(book);
    }
```

Application properties contains password and database details and JPAConfig contain JPA configuration details such as entity scan database details. When am trying to run the test case am getting an error like

```
     A component required a bean of type 
    'com.repository.sample.BookRepository' that could not be found.
```

I don't have main method in it.Am new to unit testing please anyone help me to solve the issue.

Comment: Can you try putting a @ Repository annotatation in your repository class and a @ Service annotation in your service class? Also try to substitute your @ Resource for @ Autowired in your service.

Comment: `@DataJpaTest` and `@SpringBootTest` are mutual exclusive. Either you do a sliced test `@DataJpaTest` or a full integration test `@SpringBootTest` but not both. If you want to do a full blown test write an integration test (on the other hand do you really need to test the save? You are basically testing the framework here).

Comment: @M.Deinum Actually I need to test on saving the  data.  am trying out many different ways but ends up with same error

Comment: Remove `@DataJpaTest`, remove `@AutoConfigureTestDatabase(replace=Replace.NONE)` and remove `@TestPropertySource(
      locations = "classpath:application.properties")`. Only leave `@SpringBooTest` (yes really only that without the `classes`) then restart your test.

Comment: @M.Deinum i done it but  showing same error

Comment: Then your project setup isn't correct and your `@SpringBootApplication` annotated class is probalbly not in a base package.

Comment: @M.Deinum Actually i dont have a main class so how can i put SpringBootApllication annotation.

Comment: If you don't have an `@SpringBootApplication` annotated class then why try using `@SpringBootTest`?

Comment: @M.Deinum this is my first attempt to do unit testing..my requirement is to do it as Junit testing

Comment: Unit testing isn't integration testing.

Comment: @M.Deinum so can you suggest me any method to check data saving using junit test for the above codes

Comment: Create the service and check if the save method is called. Do it without spring.